# sql query optimizer for field stastics with zero density for a specific value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to simplify the scenario so I can clarify it better.

Lets say I have a table like;

```
create table documents
    (DocumentId uniqueidentifier primary key,
    --valid values are D=Draft,P=Published,R=Revised
    documentType char(1) not null,
    PublisherId,
    ....
```

and I have a simple view on this which has the predicate 
**DocumentType != 'D'**
to filter out drafts.

and most of my queries run against this view, like PublisherId in (.....) and date > ... etc.
.

so the problem is I have 500.000 records in this table and none of them are type of **Draft**.

anyways, when I run the query and get the Actual Plan, the SMS tells me that I have a missing index on DocumentType, PublisherId and along with like 50 more fields that it wants me to include.

I expect SQL Query Optimizer to keep the stats on DocumentType field and realize that there are no documents of type Draft and not check for that flag for this query.
I have checked the stats

```
DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('Documents','DocumentType')
```

and it has the statistics.
How can I make SQL Query Optimizer skip this fields' value check in this scenario and work with another index.

Btw, I am using EntityFramework, so I dont have too much control on SQL Generation.
MSSQL version is 2012.

**EDIT:**
Looking into filtered indexes

Comment: Have you considered a filtered index? Also if SSMS is telling you you need a missing index on 50+ columns, have you considered not using SELECT *?

Comment: How would the query optimizer know from one query to the next a record D had not been inserted?  The query must be evaluated.  The query optimizer just determines the optimal way to evaluate.